# Has Google Colab stopped giving free RAM?

Tags: google-colaboratory, ram

Many sources on the Internet said that Google Colab will give you a free 25GB RAM if your session crashes. Mine crashed, but instead of getting the "Get more RAM" offer, I only got "View runtime logs". I have searched for an explanation but didn't find any one talking about this. Has Google removed the option?

[image: Mine only showed "View runtime logs"]

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Now it seems to be available to Colab Pro users only.

Comment: Thank you. It's sad to hear that. Do you know any alternative to Google Colab that offers more than 12GB of RAM?

Comment: You can pay and use GCP + Colab. You can have up to 128GB, or even more with customizing.